# Were there other clone armies created by the Kaminoans?

Tags: star-wars, clones

In Episode II, Obi-Wan finds the Kaminoans are creating a clone army for the Republic, and the prime minister of Kamino states:

> **LAMA SU:** Yes, a clone army. And, I must say, one of the finest ***we've ever created***.

Also, when Obi-Wan talks to his friend Dexter, he is familiar with the Kaminoans as good cloners.

**Is there any record of another clone army created by the Kaminoans previous to that?**

Comment: Based on the [Kamino](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kamino) and [Cloning](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cloning) entries on Wookieepedia, my guess is that they were mostly doing relatively small private armies. No mention of any other clients is made, just that Kamino learned cloning for themselves and then taught other civilizations.

Comment: The [Kaminoan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kaminoan) article on Wookieepedia states "While Kamino-made clones slaved away in the mining colonies of Subterrel or the **private armies of intergalactic mercenaries**, the Kaminoans thought nothing of it, continuing to toil toward gaining more scientific honor." Given the Kaminoans' cloning skills it's a fair assumption that they've created clone armies before, but to my knowledge we've never been told for whom or for what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any canon source which answers this question either in the affirmative or the negative. However, **the Legends novel *Darth Plagueis* suggests that the Kaminoans do not have experience creating a clone army in the military sense**. The Kaminoans have a great deal of cloning experience, but the closest they've come to creating a clone army is a clone "army" of laborers.

I've quoted the relevant parts of the book below, with my own emphasis added and links to characters added where appropriate. The information comes from a meeting between Darth Plagueis and Kaminoan scientists, in which Plagueis inquires about creating a clone army of [Yinchorri](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yinchorri) soldiers shortly before the creation of the Grand Army of the Republic.

Starting on page 199:

> Moral principles regarding natural selection seemed to be something they had left on the floor of what was now Kamino’s planetwide ocean, which perhaps explained why they were no more reluctant about providing game animals for Sojourn than they were about supplying shovel-handed clones to work in the mines of inhospitable Subterrel.
>
> ...
>
> [Hego Damask / Darth Plagueis:] “The question is, can compliance be bred into them without affecting their violent tendencies?”
>
> “Probably not without disturbing the basic personality matrix,” [Ko Sai](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ko_Sai) said. “We might produce a clone that is merely Yinchorri in aspect, but lacks the signature characteristics of the species.”
>
> Damask frowned. “That won’t do.”
>
> “Have you considered using a more acquiescent species?” [Ni Timor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ni_Timor) asked.
>
> “Which would you recommend?
>
> “One of the placid species. Ithorians, for example. Or Caamasi.”
>
> Damask shook his head. “Neither species would suit my purposes. What about humans?”
>
> “Our experience with humans is limited—though of course we have grown many replacement organs.”
>
> “Human emotionalism is somewhat problematic,” Ko Sai added, “but not unsolvable.” Damask considered the comment, and then agreed with the Kaminoan’s assessment.
>   ...
>   “Perhaps, Magister,” [Lac Nor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lac_Nor) was saying, “if we understood your plans for the Yinchorri clones.”
>
> “I would expect them to serve as soldiers.”
>
> “Ah,” Ni Timor said. “Then obedience, not mere compliance, must be a prime consideration.”
>
> “And yet the need for some measure of free will,” Ko Sai was quick to point out.
>
> “Or else why not simply use combat automata?” Lac Nor’s large eyes fixed on Damask.
>
> “These Yinchorri appear to be ready-made for war, Magister. Are there so few of them in the galaxy that you need to clone an army?”
>
> He had deliberately avoided mentioning Yinchorri immunity to Force suggestion because he should have no way of knowing about that, or indeed anything about the actions of midi-chlorians. But it was precisely the reptilians’ capability to fashion Force bubbles that he hoped to explore.
>
> “As you’ve already pointed out,” he said after a moment, “their innate bellicosity interferes with their ability to follow orders.”
>
> Mostly to himself, **Ni Timor said, “We would need to assure that their violent tendencies remained intact, while their behavior was less willful.”**
>
> **“Yes,” Damask said.**
>
> **Ko Sai craned her long neck. “Very challenging. Though perhaps if we could be supplied with a template for experimentation …”**

Starting on page 202:

> “More important,” Lac Nor said, “while we might be able to grow a few clones, **our facilities are at present inadequate to produce an army of any size**.”
>
> “**We would also need to consult with military specialists regarding programming**,” Ko Sai added.

Based on the novel, the Kaminoans:

- Typically created clones for non-military purposes (laborers, game animals, etc.)
- The Kaminoans regarded it as "very challenging" to make clones that were simultaneously violent but obedient -- both which would be important for an army of soldiers.
- The Kaminoans would need expert help to provide clones with military training.
- At the time (shortly before the creation of the Grand Army of the Republic) the Kaminoans' facilities were inadequate for the creation of an army.

All of these strongly suggest that the Kaminoans have never created a clone army in the military sense. Lama Su's comment is evidently referring to a "clone army" in the general sense of a large group of clones with a common but non-military purpose (like an "army" of laborers).

Comment: H/T to [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76217/31936) for tipping me off that the answer might be in the novel *Darth Plagueis*.