# Were there any clone armies before the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars

As we know, the Kaminoans were master cloners, as evidenced by their creation of the Grand Army of the Republic, but there were other cloning corporations as I understand (mainly because the Empire leased its major cloning operations to a company after the failed Kaminoan Rebellion). I am pretty sure if thinking logically that Palpatine is not the only maniacal evil Sith maniac out there who came up with the idea of a clone army.

My question is this: Is there any precedent in any Star Wars canon on a clone army before the Grand Army of the Republic?

Comment: Very related, but different enough that I don't think it's a dupe: [Were there other clone armies created by the Kaminoans?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74350/were-there-other-clone-armies-created-by-the-kaminoans)

Comment: Only difference is I want to know if anyone created them. Cloning was not a strictly Kamioan thing as far as I know. According to the in-game unit descriptions in Star Wars Force Unleashed game the Empire had huge cloning facilities all over the Empire not manned by Kaminoans. I am just wondering if anything similar happened before the Clone Wars.

Comment: Correct. There were Spaathi (spelling? I'm always confusing them with SC2 race) cloners as well, mentioned first in Thrawn trilogfy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to recall that in the novel "Darth Plagueis" they tell him, that if he wants an army, they'd have to enlarge their facilities, because they didn't do something on that scale before, but then go on to assure him that the enlargement would be no problem.

Comment: Who tells him? The kaminoans or another group of closers? I obviously did not read that specific piece of work.

Comment: The Kaminoans themselves.

Comment: This answers whether or not Kaminoans have created a large army before, but doesn't address whether not any *other* civilizations with cloning technology have.

Comment: I looked this up in the book and found the passage you were talking about. I've made it into an [answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76225/31936) for the question about whether or not the *Kaminoans* have created a clone army before. As @phantom42 has pointed out, this answer does not answer whether or not other cloners like [Arkanian Microtechnologies](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Arkanian_Microtechnologies) created a clone army.